# Shopify Product Variants in Google Tag Manager Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, shopify, google-tag-manager

I'm using the Google Tag Manager Data Layer to add Structured Data to a Shopify Store. I ran out of space adding all the products so I'm trying to consolidate my tags. I can get all the variables I need in the Data Layer, I just need to know how to iterate them for the Offers section in the Structured Data.

I really just need to know how to convert this to Javascript to use in Google Tag Manager:

```
"offers": [
    {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
      {
        "@type" : "Offer",
        {%- if variant.sku != blank -%}
          "sku": {{ variant.sku | json }},
        {%- endif -%}
        "availability" : "http://schema.org/{% if product.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}",
        "priceValidUntil" : {{'now' | date: '%Y-%m-%d' | json }},
        "price" : {{ variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 | json }},
        "priceCurrency" : {{ cart.currency.iso_code | json }},
        "url" : {{ shop.url | append: variant.url | json }}
      }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
    {%- endfor -%}
  ]
```

I'm trying to iterate through Offers of Structured Data that I'm adding via Google Tag Manager. This is what I have right now:

```
<script>
(function()
{
var data = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "@id": "{{TitanProductURL}}",
  "name": "{{TitanProductTitle}}",
  "url": "{{TitanProductURL}}",
  "image": [ "{{TitanProductImage}}"
    ],
  "description": "{{TitanProductDescription}}",
  "sku": "{{TitanSKU}}",
  "gtin12": "{{TitanBarcode}}",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "Titan Casket"
  },
  "offers": [],
"aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "{{TitanReviewRating}}",
    "bestRating": "5 star",
    "worstRating": "1 star",
    "ratingCount": "{{TitanReviewCount}}"
  }
}

  var productVariants = [{{TitanProductVariants}}];
  var productPrice = [{{TitanProductPrice}}];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < productVariants.length; i++) {
    data.offers.push({
        "@type" : "Offer",
        "sku": "{{TitanSKU}}",
        "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "priceValidUntil" : "{{TitanDate}}",
        "price" : productPrice[i],
        "priceCurrency" : "USD",
        "url" : productVariants[i]
    });
  }
  
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "application/ld+json";
  script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  })(document);
</script>
```

The TitanProductVariants and TitanProductPrice are Array's of each and when I Publish this tag, it shows all of the Arrays in one element, so instead of iterating through all the Variants, it shows all of them in every "url".

[image]

Would love any help!

**UPDATE**

I almost have it, but I'm running into 2 problems. This is my new code:

```
<script>
(function()
{
var data = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "@id": "{{TitanProductURL}}",
    "name": "{{TitanProductTitle}}",
    "url": "{{TitanProductURL}}",
    "image": [ "{{TitanProductImage}}"
      ],
    "description": "{{TitanProductDescription}}",
    "sku": "{{TitanSKU}}",
    "gtin12": "{{TitanBarcode}}",
    "brand": {
      "@type": "Thing",
      "name": "Titan Casket"
    },
    "offers": [],
  "aggregateRating": {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "ratingValue": "{{TitanReviewRating}}",
      "bestRating": "5 star",
      "worstRating": "1 star",
      "ratingCount": "{{TitanReviewCount}}"
    }
  }

  var variants = [{{TitanProductVariants}}];
  var prices = [{{TitanProductPrice}}];
  var len = variants.length;
  var text = "";
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
  data.offers.push({
      "@type" : "Offer",
      "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
      "priceValidUntil" : "{{TitanDate}}",
      "price" : text += prices[i]
      "priceCurrency" : "USD",
      "url" : text += variants[i]
    });
  }

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "application/ld+json";
  script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  })(document);
</script>
```

The 2 problems are:

1. Problem 1: The DataLayer Variables are pulling in Double Quotes
   around the entire array from Shopify so it thinks all the Variant
   URLs and All the Prices are 1 item. I can't figure out how to remove
   the Double Quotes.
2. Problem 2: I manually added the Product Variant URLs to see if it
   would work. It does... sort of. On the first iteration, it adds the
   first URL. But on the second, it adds the first URL *and* the second
   URL and it keeps adding the next URL in line on each corresponding
   iteration. I just need it to add 1 URL per iteration.

**UPDATE 2**

The Google Tag Manager Variables {{TitanProductVariants}} and {{TitanProductPrice}} pull in data from the Data Layer in an Array. So, {{TitanProductVariants}} pulls in a list of URLs with an appended Variant ID (e.g. https://titancasket.com/products/titan-atlas-xl-silver-metal-oversize-casket?variant=35312157720744) and {{TitanProductPrice}} pulls in each price for each Variant.

I need to loop through each of these so that if there are 10 Variants, it'll have 10 "Offer" elements in Schema, each with the Variant URL and corresponding price. The output would look like this:

```
{
      "@type" : "Offer",
      "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
      "priceValidUntil" : "2020-12-1",
      "price" : "1399.0",
      "priceCurrency" : "USD",
      "url" : "https://titancasket.com/products/titan-atlas-xl-silver-metal-oversize-casket?variant=35312157720744"
    },
{
      "@type" : "Offer",
      "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
      "priceValidUntil" : "2020-12-1",
      "price" : "1499.0",
      "priceCurrency" : "USD",
      "url" : "https://titancasket.com/products/titan-atlas-xl-silver-metal-oversize-casket?variant=35312157720744"
    }
```

... and so on for each Variant URL.

**Update 3**

Here's how I'm pulling in data to Google Tag Manager:

```
<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   window.dataLayer.push({
      'gtm_product_url': {{ shop.url | append: product.url | json }},
      'gtm_product_title' : {{ product.title | json }},
      'gtm_product_image' : {{ product.featured_media | img_url: media_size | prepend: "https:" | json }},
      'gtm_product_description' : "{{ product.description | strip_html | strip_newlines | replace: '"', '' }}",
      'gtm_date' : "{{'now' | date: '%Y-%m-%d' }}",
      'gtm_sku' : "{{ current_variant.sku }}",
        'gtm_barcode' : "{{ current_variant.barcode }}",
      'gtm_review_rating': "{{ shop.metafields.judgeme.shop_reviews_rating }}",
      'gtm_review_count': "{{ shop.metafields.judgeme.shop_reviews_count }}",
      'gtm_product_price': "{%- for variant in product.variants -%}{{ variant.price | divided_by: 100.00}}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{%- endfor -%}",
      'gtm_product_variants': "{%- for variant in product.variants -%}{{ shop.url | append: variant.url }}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{%- endfor -%}"
   });

  </script>
```

Comment: This seems about correct. What's the issue here?

Comment: This is the Liquid language used by Shopify, I need to do the same thing in Javascript and inside Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Liquid is a rendering language like PHP. You can wrap the above in normal Javascript and do the dataLayer push.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How would I wrap this in Javascript?

Comment: Can you show where you are defining TitanProduct.... variables? You're probably missing something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the variants directly from liquid.

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
data.offers.push({
    "@type" : "Offer",
    "sku": "{{variant.sku}}",
    "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceValidUntil" : "{{ 'now' | date: '%Y-%m-%d' }}",
    "price" : {{ variant.price }},
    "priceCurrency" : "USD",
    "url" : {{ shop.url | append: variant.url }}
})
{% endfor %}
```

If you are keen on using the javascript loop, try this.

```
var variants = {{ product.variants | json }};
for (let variants of variants){
  data.offers.push({
    "@type" : "Offer",
    "sku": variant.sku,
    "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceValidUntil" : "{{ 'now' | date: '%Y-%m-%d' }}",
    "price" : variant.price,
    "priceCurrency" : "USD",
    "url" : "{{ shop.url }}"+variant.url
})
```

Update #2: Based on new information

```
var productVariants = {{TitanProductVariants}}.split(',');
var productPrice = {{TitanProductPrice}}.split(',');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < productVariants.length; i++) {
  data.offers.push({
      "@type" : "Offer",
      "sku": "{{TitanSKU}}",
      "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
      "priceValidUntil" : "{{TitanDate}}",
      "price" : productPrice[i],
      "priceCurrency" : "USD",
      "url" : productVariants[i]
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the JavaScript code but it didn't work. Check out my update, would love any input from you!

Comment: What is `TitanProductVarisnts`? It looks like a liquid array drop  which you are not converting to JSON array. Did you check what the value of `len` is? I'm guessing it's `1`. Did you try the first option I presented? Share the details of `TitanProductVariants` in code.

Comment: I just updated my question (look under Update 2). Hopefully that makes more sense now. I think I may need to use a for..in loop, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see why you should use anything else that the `for...in` liquid loop. It has the entire variant data. Now that I know that `Titan...` is a GTM variable, I'm also updating the liquid and JS solutions accordingly.

Comment: I'm putting these in Google Tag Manager as Custom HTML. So anything I put in there has to have GTM Variables pulling in Data. I've create Variables for the URL Variants and Prices so I'd need to use those. So this isn't in Shopify, it has to be JavaScript inside of GTM.

Comment: Can you share how you are defining `TitanProductVariants` ?

Comment: I've just added it to the question under Update 3

Comment: Hah.. You're storing an array as a string. That's the problem. Updated the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: DUDE, thanks so much! Been working on this forever. That did it!